# typeahead / filter / JSON parse?

Tags: json, typeahead, bloodhound

Trying to 'parse/read' an external .json file on my typeahead code, but the .json file (which I cannot modify) looks like:

```
{"**cms_countries**":
  [{"**cms_country**": 
[{"**countrydisplayname**":"Afghanistan"}
 ,{"countrydisplayname":"Albania"} ,{"countrydisplayname":"Algeria"}
 ... ... ... ,{"countrydisplayname":"Zimbabwe"} ] } ,{"TotalRecords": 
 [ {"TotalRecords":"246"} ] } ] }
```

So, I think my problem is  to know how to parse/read/assimilate/integrate/adopt this .json file, having
**cms_countries** ,
**cms_country** , 
and then, my **countrydisplayname** field on it.  (have you seen the tree here ?)

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var searchablePlaces    = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer                  : Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("countrydisplayname"),
        queryTokenizer                  : Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch                        : 'countries.json',
        remote                          : {
            url                             : 'countries/%QUERY.json',
            wildcard                        : '%QUERY',
            filter                          : function(response) { return response.cms_country; }
            }, 
        limit                           : 10
        });

searchablePlaces.initialize(); 

        $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(
        {
        hint            : true,
        highlight       : true,
        minLength       : 2
        },
        {
        name            : 'countrydisplayname',
        displayKey      : "countrydisplayname",
        source          : searchablePlaces.ttAdapter()
        })
});
```

But of course, it is not working:

ANY hint on how to organize my filter... ?  or how to do to overcome my `nested .json` wrappers....

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've got my code working now:

```
$(window).load(function(){   
    var movies = new Bloodhound({
        limit: 10,
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: { 
            url: 'countries.json',
            filter: function (movies) {  
                return $.map(movies.cms_countries[0].cms_country, function (paises) {  
                    return {        
                        value: paises.countrydisplayname 
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });

    // Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
    movies.initialize(); 

    // Instantiate the Typeahead UI
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(
        {
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, 
        {
        //displayKey: 'value',
        displayKey: function (toto) {
                  return toto.value;
              },
        source: movies.ttAdapter()
    });
});
```